# database insertion issue

Tags: ios, sqlite

i am getting trouble in adding data to database and this is so weird problem

when i add data with only 2 arguments like below

```
for(int i=0; i<_birthdateincontects.count; i++){

        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
        int x;

        char *update = "insert into PersonNamesAndBirthDates (Names,Birthdates) values(?,?);";
        x = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, update, -1, &stmt, nil);

        if (x == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_namesincontects objectAtIndex:i]]);
            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_birthdateincontects objectAtIndex:i]]);



            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_namesincontects objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_birthdateincontects objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);


            if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){}

             sqlite3_finalize(stmt);


    }
```

then it works perfectly and add loop happen 3 times and data gets add

but when i try to add like this

```
for(int i=0; i<_birthdateincontects.count; i++){

        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
        int x;

        char *update = "insert into PersonNamesAndBirthDates (Names,Birthdates,Profilepic) values(?,?,?);";
        x = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, update, -1, &stmt, nil);

        if (x == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_namesincontects objectAtIndex:i]]);
            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_birthdateincontects objectAtIndex:i]]);
            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"No Image"]);


            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_namesincontects objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_birthdateincontects objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
             sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"No Image"] UTF8String],-1, NULL);


            if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){}

             sqlite3_finalize(stmt);


    }
```

then same like above loop runs 3 times but in database only 1st raw get added and other time loop run but nothing get added why this is happening is way of my head. plz 
suggest something and make me out of this discombobulation

NOTE: nslog print value perfectly

Comment: sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Image"] UTF8String],-1, NULL);

Comment: tried same thing happened

Comment: Are you getting the data three times when NSLog? And also try to add sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_namesincontects objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL); three times, instead of different values.

Comment: yes nslog print values

Comment: what you mean three times instead of different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often when SQL statements fail, you can look at `sqlite3_errmsg` and it will tell you what's gone wrong, e.g.:

```
for(int i=0; i < _birthdateincontects.count; i++){

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int x;

    char *update = "insert into PersonNamesAndBirthDates (Names,Birthdates,Profilepic) values(?,?,?);";
    x = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, update, -1, &stmt, nil);

    if (x == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_namesincontects objectAtIndex:i]]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_birthdateincontects objectAtIndex:i]]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"No Image"]);

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_namesincontects objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_birthdateincontects objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [@"No Image" UTF8String],-1, NULL);

        if ((x = sqlite3_step(stmt)) != SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"%s: step failed: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database1), x);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: prepare failed: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database1), x);
    }
}
```

---

By the way, you can also make this more efficient by not re-preparing the SQL every time, e.g.:

```
char *update = "insert into PersonNamesAndBirthDates (Names,Birthdates,Profilepic) values(?,?,?);";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int x;

if ((x = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, update, -1, &stmt, nil)) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"%s: prepare failed: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database1), x);
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < _birthdateincontects.count; i++)
{
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_namesincontects objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_birthdateincontects objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, "No Image", -1, NULL);

    if ((x = sqlite3_step(stmt)) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"%s: step failed: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database1), x);
    }

    sqlite3_reset(stmt);
}

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Comment: @user2189388 BTW, if I neglected to say it, I don't see anything that would cause the behavior you describe. Hopefully the `sqlite3_errmsg` will identify the issue (maybe unique key violation ... I don't know). Also, I've revised my answer with a slightly optimized version that refrains from re-preparing the SQL every time.

Comment: i was so confused yesterday and then at last i went home and had dinner and slept. but in my dreams i was seeing my computer and then i  dreamed about that my Profilepic field has unique key constraint thanks to my dreams and you Rob :)

Comment: @user2189388 This is why I put a `NSLog` upon errors in `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, but also `sqlite3_step`. For example, using the above code, if you had used the `NSLog` I suggested, it would have reported "step failed: column Profilepic is not unique (19)", and would have lead you precisely to the source of your problem. If you have problems, check all the return codes and call `sqlite3_errmsg`. 15-30 seconds of code can save you hours of diagnostic and debugging time.